# Only trigger event while form field is focused

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form, and I trigger a Bootstrap popover whenever the user focuses on a particular field. The problem is that I want this event *while* the user is focused on the field - at the moment the event stays triggered once you focus on another field. This also needs to work without confliction with a click event.

Thanks for the help :)

Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
$("#pw1").on("focus", function() {
    $("#s_pw1_pop").popover('toggle');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="s_pw1_pop" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="The event is triggered">
    <div class="input-group" id="s_pw1_focus">
        <input id="pw1" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div id="s_pw1" style="position: relative; top: 7px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, incorrectly flagged as duplicate.

Comment: I've edited it, it's not the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the blur event

```
<div class="form-group" id="s_pw1_pop" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="The event is triggered" data-trigger="manual">
    <div class="input-group" id="s_pw1_focus">
        <input id="pw1" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div id="s_pw1_popover"></div>
    <div id="s_pw1" style="position: relative; top: 7px;"></div>
</div>
```

then

```
$("#pw1").on("focus blur ", function (e) {
    $('#s_pw1_pop').popover('toggle');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oj0noqhe/)

Comment: Thanks :) is there a way to make this work with click events too?

Comment: Just use: `$("#pw1").on("focus blur click", function (e) {` ;)